# Remap Workspace Overview shortcut (Command+S)

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts

I'd like to remap Command+s to save files in Atom, but I can't figure out where to disable the workspace overview feature that's already mapped to it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can change the key `show-desktop` in `org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings` via `dconf-editor` or `gsettings` in a terminal window. It defaults to `['<Super>Down', '<Super>s']` so if you only want to disable <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd> you can set it to ['down'] for instance.

```
$ gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings show-desktop "['<Super>down']"
```