# Super + S: How do I change this?

Tags: release-loki

I'm wondering where I can re-set this function (zoom out and show all workspaces) in elementary OS?

Comment: This is a duplicate of http://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/10101/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the key `show-desktop` in `org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings` via `dconf-editor` or `gsettings` in a terminal window. It defaults to `['<Super>Down', '<Super>s']` so if you only want to disable <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd> you can set it to `[<Super>Down]` for instance.

```
$ gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings show-desktop "['<Super>down']"
```