# How to revert Super to Super + Space?

Tags: release-loki, menu

I changed the Super+Space shortcut to Super using some command I don't remember now (It's been 2-3 weeks). But I don't like it, it gets in the way many times during my work, and also Super+Space never got removed, Super simply gained the shortcut and it now exists for both shortcuts. So, I want to go back.

How can I remove the Super shortcut for the application menu?

Comment: As your question got bumped to the community I'm wondering if any answer was a solution?

Comment: yeah, updated the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From gxg's help the command is:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.mutter overlay-key " "
```

Change it to empty space:" "

I used `dconf-editor` to check the value of `org.gnome.mutter overlay-key` and found it was `Super_L` from the answer [linked here](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/11300/super-s-how-do-i-change-this?rq=1).

`Dconf-editor` can also be used to change the value.

Answer (score 2):

Probably you did use the command gXg pointed out. To revert changes, do:

```
gsettings reset org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings panel-main-menu
```

Answer (score 1):

To open application search only by pressing Super(win) key:

gsettings set org.gnome.mutter overlay-key "'Super_L'"
gsettings set org.pantheon.desktop.gala.behavior overlay-action "'wingpanel --toggle-indicator=app-launcher'"

Now you should reverse engineer these commands. Hope it helps.